# Serialization taking way too long

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xamarin, uwp

So I am working on an UWP app that I'm creating in a portable class library (Xamarin). I need to save information that are typed in (e.g. in TextBoxes) by a user in an xml file.

Therefore I created a class in PCL where I get the info from those TextBoxes:

```
namespace myProject
{
    public class XMLData
    {
        [XmlRoot("MyRootElement")]
        public class MyRootElement
        {
            [XmlAttribute("MyAttribute1")] //name of the xml element
            public string MyAttribute1     //name of a textboxt e.g.
            {
                get;
                set;
            }
            [XmlAttribute("MyAttribute2")]
            public string MyAttribute2
            {
                get;
                set;
            }
            [XmlElement("MyElement1")]
            public string MyElement1
            {
                get;
                set;
            }
    }
}
```

On each Page there is a "continue" button. When clicked, the data gets saved:

```
async void Continue_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new Page2());
            XMLData.MyRootElement mre = new XMLData.MyRootElement
            {
                MyAttribute1 = editor1.ToString(),
                MyAttribute2 = editor2.ToString(),
                MyElement1 = editor3.ToString()
            };
        }
```

At the last button click the file should be created and saved:

```
private void CreateandSave_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var s = DependencyService.Get<IFileHelper>().MakeFileStream();//using dependencyService to get a stream (there is no system.io.stream in PCL)
            XMLData xmldat = new XMLData();
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(s, Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(XMLData));
                serializer.Serialize(sw, xmldat);
            }
        }
```

Here my code in the UWP class (for dependencyService I created a class called FileHelper to get a stream and create a saving location + file)

```
namespace myProject.UWP
{
    public class FileHelper: IFileHelper //IFileHelper is a simple interface I made with the Stream MakeFileStream(); method in it
    {
        public async Task<IRandomAccessStream> MakeFileStreamAsync()
        {
            StorageFolder sf = KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary;

            var file = await sf.CreateFileAsync("data.xml", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
            using (var stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
            {
                return stream;
            }
        }
        Stream IFileHelper.MakeFileStream()
        {
            var task = MakeFileStreamAsync();
            task.Wait();
            return task.Result.AsStreamForWrite();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that whenever I reach the CreateandSave button and click on it, the app just freezes. No errors, nothing, everything looks fine. After I break up the debugging I can see that there is an xml file created in the folder I wanted but it's empty (0 bytes). What's wrong with the code? Anyone an idea?

Comment: Why don't you add a method to the interface like "WriteStringToFileAsync(string s)" and then implement it on every platform. So you don't have to pass the stream between the two classes. This should make it a lot easier to debug.

Comment: @Malte I'm pretty new to programming and I think that your suggestion would exceed my understanding. I don't quite understand what you mean or how I would implement that. But thank you anyway for your suggestion, I appreciate it!

Comment: You could add a method "WriteStringToFileAsync(string s)" to your interface IFileHelper instead of MakeFileStream, implement this method on every platform (e.g. UWP with Windows.Storage.FileIO.WriteTextAsync) then serialize your data to an XML string get the implementation of IFileHelper from the DependencyService and pass the string to the WriteStringToFile method.
I hope this helps you to understand what I was trying to explain.

Comment: @Malte got it, thanks! But the problem of freezing still remains :(

Comment: In what line of code does the freezing start?

Comment: @Malte I can't even tell that because whereever I put the breakpoints in the clicked_handler, I get the `the breakpoint will not currently be hit. no symbols have been loaded for this document` error. What I know is that it occures when I click on the _CreateandSave_ button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your freeze problem is that the `Task.Wait()` instruction blocks the main UI thread until `MakeFileStreamAsync()` method finishes execution.

You should make this method `async` and returning a `Task<Stream>` type, and call the `MakeFileStreamAsync` method using the await keyword:

```
async Task<Stream> IFileHelper.MakeFileStream()
{
    var stream = await MakeFileStreamAsync();
    return stream.AsStreamForWrite();
}
```

Therefore, your code for the creation click should be something like:

```
private void CreateandSave_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var s = DependencyService.Get<IFileHelper>().MakeFileStream();//using dependencyService to get a stream (there is no system.io.stream in PCL)
    XMLData xmldat = new XMLData();

    // Here you should await your `s` Task:
    await s;

    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(s, Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(XMLData));
        serializer.Serialize(sw, xmldat);
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!

**EDIT:**
Regarding your empty xml file problem, I think it's because you save the data in another page, but don't do anything with it. Which means you lose them when loading the `Page2`. Therefore, they are not available in the `CreateandSave_Clicked` method and you currently save an empty XMLData object.

The more intuitive way is passing the data to your `Page2` constructor and add this datatype as a public property of `Page2`. So your `Continue_Clicked` method would look like:

```
async void Continue_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Note you must REVERSE instructions here
    // Create first your object (save the user data in it)
    XMLData.MyRootElement mre = new XMLData.MyRootElement
    {
        MyAttribute1 = editor1.ToString(),
        MyAttribute2 = editor2.ToString(),
        MyElement1 = editor3.ToString()
    };
    // Pass it to Page2 through the constructor
    await Navigation.PushAsync(new Page2(mre));
}
```

And so the `Page2` class/contructor becomes:

```
public class Page2 : SomeParentClass
{
   ...
   // add your XMLData property
   public XMLData.MyRootElement mre { get; set; }
   ...
   // the constructor
   public Page2(XMLData.MyRootElement data){
       // Save the user data in xmldat property. So this data could be reused later.
       this.mre = data;
   }
}
```

Then, if it's `Page2` that is responsible of creating and saving the XML file itself, you can reuse the object you passed through the constructor.

```
private void CreateandSave_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var s = DependencyService.Get<IFileHelper>().MakeFileStream();//using dependencyService to get a stream (there is no system.io.stream in PCL)
    // You want to remove that here as you created a public property of type XMLData.MyRootElement (called mre) holding user data instead 
    //XMLData xmldat = new XMLData();

    // Here you should await your `s` Task:
    await s;

    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(s, Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        // Change of serialized type here
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(XMLData.MyRootElement));
        // Here, just seralize the property saved through constructor
        serializer.Serialize(sw, mre);
    }
}
```

Note that if it's `Page3` or whatever `Page` that is responsible of saving the XML file, just keep passing the saved user data from page to page and save them once when you call the `CreateandSave_Clicked` method.

Another point is that I am not sure of the usefulness of nesting `MyRootElement` class into `XMLData`. You could just remove the `XMLData` nesting class and just keep the `MyRootElement` class as the "main" one.

You could also achieve the same using static fields as well and therefore not using the constructor. But from my point of view, it's less intuitive and moreover, less clean.

Enjoy,

Comment: Thank you @TaiT's ! Can you explain to me how `await s;` works? What do I have to add before? Because "The type or namespace name 'await'..." error comes up.

Comment: okay I got it now and no freezing! It works! Thank you so much! The only problem now is that the xml file is empty :( The template is there but none of my elements, any idea?

Comment: Glad it helped! For more info, I've found [this microsoft page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674882.aspx) very helpful while learning this topic. Async/Await is really easy to understand but difficult to master ;). Take a look especially at the schema in the **What Happens in an Async Method** section. 
Regarding your empty file, I might have a look later, now I run out of time :)

Comment: I will, thank you a lot! Alright but please don't forget me and have a look at it later if you have some time to spend :) Have a nice day!

Comment: alright after 5 hours I figured out that it's not allowed to have more than one rootElement (class) or else I can't pass the arguments.. I will try tomorrow again and see what I can make. Thank you so so much!

Answer (score 2):

In this piece of code:

```
using (var stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
{
    return stream;
}
```

you are returning an instance created by the `using` block. It will be disposed before the return, and as a result, you're returning a disposed object.

Change it to just `return stream`. The `StreamWriter` you use is in a `using` block itself, so during its disposal [it will dispose the underlying stream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtbhzte9(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The `StreamWriter` object calls `Dispose()` on the provided `Stream` object when `StreamWriter.Dispose` is called.

Comment: Okay so I have to write it outside of the `using` right? @BartoszKP

Comment: @RoloffM Yes, the simplest fix is to remove this using block.

Comment: Thank you! I've changed the code now but the problem still remains. No erro whatsoever but the app just freezes...

Comment: @RoloffM Seems there's is some another problem in asynchronous structure of your app :/ I'll look into it, but I'm not very experienced in that matter.

Comment: thank you Sir, I appreciate it! The problem is that I'm not an expert on that field either :(